# How to enable the Plug-In Selection Spy in the Target Platform?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

Is there a way to enable / disable the Plug-In Selection Spy in the Target Platform i.e. RCP product?

Currently it only works in my eclipse environment with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, but not in the Target Platform.
I have added the `org.eclipse.pde.runtime` plugin in the run configuration - I still can't activate the Plug-In Selection Spy.

Comment: I can see the plug-in spy, but my target contains the complete JDT and PDE. Did you check that the `org.eclipse.pde.runtime` plug-in is actually resolved? It has optional dependencies on `jdt.ui`, `jdt.core`, `core.resources`, `pde.ui` and `help` (sigh), maybe one of them isn't oh so optional...

Comment: It's weird because I have included all the eclipse plugins in my run configuration, and all of the plugins are resolved in the target platform. And still, I can't activate the plug-in selection spy.

Comment: Did you try to set a breakpoint in the SpyHandler (or whatever it is called) to see if it gets thus far?

Comment: I'm not sure how can I do that. It looks like it's an internal class: org.eclipse.pde.internal.runtime.spy.dialogs.SpyDialog .

Comment: Internal or not doesn't matter. If your target contains sources (whcih it should anyway) you can open `org.eclipse.pde.internal.runtime.spy.handlers.SpyHandler` (not the one from `org.eclipse.ui...`) and set a breakpoint at the very beginning of its execute() method.

Comment: I did that in the debugging mode, and it seems like the handler is not activated. Maybe I could create a command associated with this handler - I think I will try this.

Comment: There is already a command for this handler (see the `plugin.xml` of `org.eclipse.pde.runtime`) you shoud ltry to find out why either the key binding doesn't work or why the command isn't active.

Comment: I have tried to manually add a command and a key binding for that command - it seems that there has been some customization done for the project that I work in, so that the key bindings are disabled somehow. I will further investigate this, but at least I know that this something project-specific.

Comment: Wait! I was doing it wrong, it works! :) After deleting the `contextId` from the binding scheme, the Plug-In Selection Spy is working. But I need to manually add it as a command in the `plugin.xml`. Maybe this has something to do with the product.

Comment: Thanks,  Rüdiger! :)